# What is the default /etc/inittab file on a fresh install of Debian Jessie?

Tags: debian, systemd, configuration, init

I'm looking for the full contents of the default `/etc/inittab` file on a fresh install of Debian 8.7 before any system-specific modifications are made.

I searched for this on the Debian website and other forums, but could not find it.

Answer (score 5):

`/etc/inittab` is installed by the `sysvinit` package. You can see the default version for Jessie [here](https://sources.debian.net/src/sysvinit/2.88dsf-59/debian/share/inittab/), and the current default version [here](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/sysvinit/blob/master/debian/share/inittab).

A new install of Jessie generally won’t have an `/etc/inittab` file at all, it’s not necessary with systemd.